# How to get the payment method used to save in order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, payment

I've built a custom payment method, everything works.
but when I check the order on dashboard the payment method information is not saved.

How do I go about this?

[image: its blank]

Comment: What information about your payment method, you have stored at the database.

Comment: ive used the self.placeOrder function. assumed that it would store my offline payment method title on the order

Comment: i store the payment method name